# CGAL Error: Eigen3 is required -> Eigen seems to be okay though

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, eigen, cgal

When running my program with this CGAL include for example:

```
#include <CGAL/Epick_d.h>
```

I get two error messages that read:

```
C1189 #error: Eigen3 is required
```

and

```
#error directive: Requires Eigen
```

They direct to cartesian_la_base.h and constructors.h respectively.
There I find the following piece of code:

```
#ifndef CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED 
#error Requires Eigen
#endif
```

So it seems to me that the CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED flag is not set. I cannot find a problem with either CGAL or Eigen though, so I am a bit puzzled as to why this is happening.
I set an environment variable to .../Eigen and included the directory under Properties -> c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories as well as
in Linker -> General.

Strangely enough, there seems to be virtually no-one else to receive the same error-message, judging from my success with googling the matter.

I use Visual Studio 2015.

Hopefully this is enough information.
Cheers

Comment: Do you have a copy of Eigen on your computer? In the solution directory? Somewhere else? If so, where (full redacted path)? What relevant Additional Include Directories do you have set?

Comment: Did you or cmake not define `CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED`? Does your cmake file have the lines: `find_package(Eigen3 3.1.0)
  if (EIGEN3_FOUND)
  include( ${EIGEN3_USE_FILE} )
endif()` (sorry for the lack of newlines in comments)?

Comment: Simply define `CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED` and you should be fine then. This flag is supposed to be set when including the use file of Eigen in cmake.

Comment: #define CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED seems to work. That is surprisingly easy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding the line

```
#define CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED
```

solved the problem. So it seems the only issue was the flag not being set correctly.

Comment: Apparently I can´t accept my own answer for 2 more days. Sorry for spam

Comment: Don't be sorry, this can indeed be surprising, and it is useful to have the information here. Note that starting with CGAL-4.10, on compilers that support `__has_include`, the macro will be automatically defined.